# CSOM OAuth Download from SharePoint Online - The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: sharepoint, oauth, csom

*I am Authenticating to Azure API using clientID, Thumbprint, Certificate, TenantID.  I am trying to
download a file but getting an error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. When
Authenticating with Username and Password it works fine. Any help here would be great thanks.
When I try to Upload using either authentication method it works fine. The only issue is this code for downloading*

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Security;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
    using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
 
 
      namespace UploadSH365
      {
     class DownloadFile
     {
    public string Download(string vURL, string site, out string vFileout, string vUName, string vPWD, string vList, string vFolder, string vFileName, string clientId, string thumbPrint, string tenantId)
    {
        string siteUrl = vURL + site;
        string strMsg = "";
        vFileout = "";
        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vURL))
            return "Empty URL field";
        try
        {
            string vDlFile = "";
            ClientContext clientContext = null;
            if (vUName != "")
            {
                clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
                SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in vPWD.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(vUName, passWord);
            }
            else
            {
                var scopes = new string[] { vURL + "/.default" };
               
                var accessToken = Task.Run(() =>          GetApplicationAuthenticatedClient(clientId, ThumbPrint, scopes, tenantId)).Result;
                clientContext = GetClientContextWithAccessToken(siteUrl, accessToken);
            }
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            string vFolderpath = "";
                string vListpath = "";
                if (vFolder != "")
                {  vFolderpath = vFolder + "/"; }
                if (vList != "")
                { vListpath = vList + "/"; }
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File files = web.GetFileByUrl(vListpath + vFolderpath + vFileName);
            clientContext.Load(files);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                
               FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, files.ServerRelativeUrl);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) 
                {
               fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(ms);
               byte[] DocByte = ms.ToArray();
               vDlFile = Convert.ToBase64String(DocByte);
                }
            
            vFileout = "<Root>          \r\n<SPDownload>          " + vDlFile + "</SPDownload>          \r\n</Root>          ";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strMsg = ex.Message;
        }
        return strMsg;
    }
    internal static async Task<string>          GetApplicationAuthenticatedClient(string clientId, string certThumprint, string[] scopes, string tenantId)
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = GetAppOnlyCertificate(certThumprint);
        IConfidentialClientApplication clientApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                              .Create(clientId)
                              .WithCertificate(certificate)
                              .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                              .Build();
        AuthenticationResult authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
        string accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;
        return accessToken;
    }
    public static ClientContext GetClientContextWithAccessToken(string targetUrl, string accessToken)
    {
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(targetUrl);
        clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest +=
            delegate (object oSender, WebRequestEventArgs webRequestEventArgs)
            {
                webRequestEventArgs.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] => "Bearer " + accessToken;
            };
        return clientContext;
    }
    private static X509Certificate2 GetAppOnlyCertificate(string thumbPrint)
    {
        X509Certificate2 appOnlyCertificate = null;
        using (X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
        {
            certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbPrint, false);
            if (certCollection.Count >          0)
            {
                appOnlyCertificate = certCollection[0];
            }
            certStore.Close();
            return appOnlyCertificate;
            }
         }
     }
      }
```

Comment: Is this tenant created after 2020.8.26？

Comment: I believe it was before. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I have tracked down the issue to be with this linebelow. The error is: System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.'

     FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, files.ServerRelativeUrl);

Comment: OK it appears OpenBinaryDirect is not able to see the token. Instead I had to use OpenBinaryStream.

    ClientResult<Stream> fileInfo = files.OpenBinaryStream();

                // Load the Stream data for the file
                clientContext.Load(files);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    fileInfo.Value.CopyTo(ms);
                    byte[] DocByte = ms.ToArray();
                    vDlFile = Convert.ToBase64String(DocByte);
                }